# Lost dog in Skyrim V

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I had Villagence and I went and did some quest, This was at like lvl 10 and i lost villagence while doing it and now i apparently still "Have him" but he doesnt follow me anywhere and i can't find him. It wont let me get another because i still "Have" him. And i got the DLC and i want one of the hell hounds. I'm a level 32 so i don't want to go back and find the sucker so i can get another.

Answer (score 2):

You probably told him to wait somewhere. Try pressing <kbd>~</kbd> and entering `player.moveto 0009a7ab` if you're playing on PC.

If you play on Xbox, retrace your steps to where you might have told him to wait. Followers/pets are supposed to return to the default location after a few days, but that often does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Fast traveling should get him ahead to you. Or else try waiting. If it still occurs, try going back to the Markarth Stable and see if he's there. If you can't talk to him, talk to the guy who sold the dog to you and pay again.