# My dog is missing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nintendo-switch

I was playing Skyrim on my Nintendo Switch, and I was in Fort Dawnguard. I was about to go up one of the staircases, but I put my Switch down for a second and accidentally shot my stray dog with the crossbow I had equipped.

He was alive, so I made sure he didn't turn on me. He didn't, so I went up the stairs and onto the roof. I saw him follow me up the stairs, but I'm not sure if he followed me onto the roof. After a while of looking around, I jumped over the wall and down to one of the lower roof platforms. When I went back, I couldn't find him anywhere.

I tried buying a troll, I tried recruiting Sceolang, I tried fast traveling, I tried waiting, and nothing worked.

Comment: Is this the same question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255487/lost-dog-in-skyrim-v?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen You can't use console commands on the Switch.

Comment: @Joachim yes, I know. That would be too easy, wouldn't it? The problem is still the same.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I don't get your point - it wouldn't be *too* easy. And although the problem is indeed the same, they require different solutions.

Answer (score 5):

'[Stray dogs](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Stray_Dog)' are easily lost (as their name implies).

Your only options, seemingly, are to

- **load a save game from before** your abusive behaviour;
- **recruit the dog Meeko**, as this will get rid of your current (unfindable) companion:

  > Visiting and recruiting Meeko will automatically boot the Dragonborn's animal companion, including a missing dog. The player can then dismiss Meeko and recruit other animals.

  [Meeko](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Meeko) can be found "*by the road to the south of Meeko's Shack in Hjaalmarch*".